# Retrieve a Shared Publication List using AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, publicationlist

I'm writing an AMPScript code where I need to do some updates into a **shared** publication list. By using the listId or listName properties it always returns me 0 records, but if I try with a not shared list works fine.

Is there a way, like DEs that you need to include the **ENT.** prefix, to return data from a **shared publication list**?

Here is what I'm trying right now:

```
set @rr = CreateObject("RetrieveRequest")
SetObjectProperty(@rr, "ObjectType", "List")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr, "Properties", "ID")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr, "Properties", "ListName")

set @rf= CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
SetObjectProperty(@rf, "Property", "ID") /* I've already tried using ListID */
SetObjectProperty(@rf, "SimpleOperator", "equals")
AddObjectArrayItem(@rf, "Value", <the id retrieved from the GUI>)

SetObjectProperty(@rr, "Filter", @rf)
set @response= InvokeRetrieve(@rr)
```